# OpenGL + VC++ - lighting randomly messed up in release configuration

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, visual-c++

So, I'm almost finished with my little program. The problem is that the game should look like this:

[image: Bright game]

...but it sometimes looks like this:

[image: Dim game]

This never happens in Debug configuration, only in Release. I'm using VS 2015.

I set up my lights like this:

```
GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0, 20, 0 };
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

The ball and the playing field are located in (0, 0, 0) and (0, -1, 0), respectively. Does anyone know what's causing this? Does the game retain something from the last run that messes up with the settings?

The whole project is pretty large by now, so I didn't include all of the code, but I can provide more information if you need it.

Comment: For the future: isolate a [minimal complete part of the code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it. Also stop using the deprecated legacy fixed-function API and move to the modern OpenGL programmable pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_POSITION` gets homogeneous coordinates, so it should be:

```
GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0, 20, 0, 1 };
```

or

```
GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0, 20, 0, 0 };
```

depending on whether you want a point light or a directional light.

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved by setting the light to be a point light, i.e. the last coordinate is `1`.